# Jasper Reports generating blank cells for an instance and populate value if rerun for same instance again

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using jasper reports 4.1.1 when i am exporting the report in excel some cells appears blanks for the same data set and when the report is rerun again the data gets populated.

The above problem is occurring randomly.

```
JasperPrint print=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jrXmlPathList.get(i),parameters,conn);
list.add(print); OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(reportVO.getxFilePath()));
JRXlsxExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsxExporter();
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE,Boolean.TR‌​UE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.SHEET_NAMES, sheetnames); 
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, list); 
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output); 
exporterXLS.exportReport();
```

Comment: JasperPrint print=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jrXmlPathList.get(i),parameters,conn);
     list.add(print);

  OutputStream output
  = new FileOutputStream(new File(reportVO.getxFilePath()));
  JRXlsxExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsxExporter(); 
  exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE,Boolean.TRUE);
  exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.SHEET_NAMES, sheetnames);
  exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, list);
  exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, output); 
  exporterXLS.exportReport();

Comment: the above print object contains my data which is exported through  JRXlsxExporter .Some data cells becomes blank in some instance and if the report is rerun for the same instance then the data cells gets populated

Comment: hi Alex,
Can you please help me on this or do i ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File xlsx = new File("C:/Users/Sadagopan/Documents/sample.xlsX");
JRXlsxExporter Xlsxexporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
Xlsxexporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
Xlsxexporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, xlsx);
Xlsxexporter.exportReport();
```